# LAN8742AI-CZ-TR GND pad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ethernet

I am working on [LAN8742AI-CZ-TR](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DS_LAN8742_00001989A.pdf). GND pin is "hidden" under the chip. Am I ok to use simple via to the GND polygon on my Bottom Layer (it's a simple 2 layer board)? Eagle CAD is complaining when I am trying to do this. Can I ignore it and is it not going to be a problem with manufacturing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to consider and control where and how the solder paste is applied, and how to prevent or compensate for the said solder paste from flowing into the via.

Comment: For hand assembly that is fine. A tiny bit of solder will be wicked into the via, but if it's tented on the opposite side it won't be able to wick further. For high volume manufacturing you might be concerned about yields since a variable amount of solder could be left on the pad.

Comment: Before anything else, `it's a simple 2 layer board` are you sure you want to do this on a 2L board? You are aware of the fact that the trace widths and separations to meet the "100 Ohm diff impedance" requirement become more "strange" as the board thickness increases, aren't you? The pad width is 0.3 mm (max) for this footprint, and you may end up with 0.7-mm-wide traces for a 1-mm-thick 2L FR4 PCB. Anyway. As for your main question, it should be fine but make sure the bottom plane is GND, not anything else or a floating copper pour. Also, not sure but Eagle may not be happy with vias on pads.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I am fairly new to the whole pcb design world so honest answer is - no, I wasn't aware of the things you mentioned. Thank you for explaining. When you say that my bottom layer should be GND and nothing else. It's currently set to fill remining space with GND using ratsnest function in Eagle on both top and bottom layers. I do however use bottom layer to jump signals too . Is that going to be an issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is better than a simple via will be multiple vias, to have lower resistance and inductance from the pad to the ground plane, as that is the return path for all currents, for both power and signals, for both analog and digital. There are fast noisy digital signals and sensitive analog signals.

But, please understand that what you are now doing on a 2 layer board would under normal circumstances be done on 4 layer board by default, without even thinking about using only 2 layers.  So if it does not work properly, it's likely due to PCB design.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I used 4 layer board how would you normaly setup different layers ?
L1(Top) - elements, signals
L2 - GND
L3 - VCC
L4(Bottom) - elements, signals ?

Multiple vias as in just x4 vias on that pad ?

Comment: Yes, depending on which side the chip is, e.g. top, that might be the best layer  for the impedance controlled signals, and ground plane should be the next layer, then supply planes/ground/something, and bottom layer as non-critical signals. Yes multiple vias - maybe one in each corner, or five like dots in a die, or depending on pad size and drill size, nine for 3x3 pattern.